# Why do i need the general $(n+1)th$ derivative for $ln$ problems using Lagrange error bound instead of simply the maximum value on that interval?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm doing a problem set in Khan Academy on Lagrange error bound, and this confuses me.  For several problems in this format:

> Estimating $e^{-0.8}$ using a Taylor series polynomial about $x=1$, what is the least degree necessary to assure the error is less than 0.001?

For problems like this I find the derivative of the given function, find its maximum value $M$, and then use trial-and-error to choose the necessary degree, which is usually between 3 and 6.  I use this inequality:
$$R_n\leq \frac{M}{(n+1)!}(x-c)^{n+1}
$$

But problems with an original function of $ln(x)$ keep appearing.  For these I try the same process, finding the derivative, finding its maximum value, and then trial and error. But my answer is always wrong.  Instead, the solution expects me to...

- find the (n+1)th derivative in a general form
- simplifying it
- creating a new inequality like this:

$$R_n\leq \frac{\frac{(-1)^nn!}{x^{n+1}}}{(n+1)!}(x-c)^{n+1}
$$

- creating another new inequality using some point $z$ on the interval from x to c, and then using trial and error to find the desired degree.

Why doesn't it work to simply take the derivative of the original function, find its maximum value, and then solve?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  For any given numerical problem, there are likely to be many approaches that work.  Of course, some might be more efficient than others...that tends to depend on specifics.  Here, just guessing, we might note that, for positive $x$, the usual power series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ is an alternating series whose terms decrease to $0$.  That's a great situation, the error is simply bounded by the first omitted term.  But, as I say, other methods are better in other contexts.